# Can't identify CSS or element controlling background color

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

I'm having trouble changing the background color of a certain button on a WordPress plugin.

The button and text are set to white and I'm trying to identify the CSS file that controls it, unfortunately I've had no luck within the inspect element of my browser.

It is incorporated in a popup form - so multiple other files come into play.

I changed the color within the browser during inspect but need a fix.

[image: Button]

[image: Inspected Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite CSS attributes by setting !important after your definition or by defining the scope better (e.g. by writing body or html before the class selector).
make sure your css file is able to "access" the dom element – if the element is in an iframe the css wont work.

```
body .wpforms-page-button {
     background-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: Using `!important` is like entering a cheat when playing a game - it's best regarded as a development tool. It's not really ideal to use `!important` in a production environment.

Comment: @Rounin - thats why I suggested to define the scope better. Sometimes, especially when having to change widgets there is no way around using !important. 
It is a valid solution. If it is the best solution for a given problem has to be determined on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

Using !important is generally considered hacky. Both rules in your screenshot have the same CSS specificity in that they are both firing on input[type="submit"] and .button.

Without seeing the corresponding HTML I can't give you the exact syntax, but something like

.parentclassname input[type='submit'] and or .parentclassname .button should make your style more specific than the original rule and therefore give it precedence.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to set !important after the #fff; ?

like this:

```
input[type=submit] {
background-color: #fff!important;
}
```

the best way is to define the button in a class, so you can change only the color for this specific button. Otherwise it will changes all the buttons to color #fff if you put the css in a general style.

Comment: My main issue is identifying where the button is drawing it's CSS from...hence inspecting via browser. If I know controlling CSS then I will modify.